# delay() not working inside loop() block

Tags: code-review

Edited and attached code here.
This section didn't execute.
The `delay(15000);` doesn't execute, I mean the sketch didn't execute this line no matter where to put it.

```cpp
    // include the SPI library:
    #include <SPI.h>

    // set pin 53 as the slave select for the digital pot:
    const int slaveSelectPin = 53; //WAS 10 on Arduino uno.
    const int shutdownPin = 7; // was 7 on uno.
    const int wiper0writeAddr = B00000000;
    const int wiper1writeAddr = B00010000;
    const int tconwriteAddr = B01000000;

    const int tcon_0off_1on = B11110000;
    const int tcon_0on_1off = B00001111;
    const int tcon_0off_1off = B00000000;
    const int tcon_0on_1on = B11111111;

    const int analogInPin_c = A5;  // center Vc=Vss/2 from the PAD, use for set ini V. here no use, Vc directly goes to pad.

    const int analogInPin_x = A1;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
    const int analogInPin_y = A2;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to

    const int analogOutPin_x = wiper0writeAddr; // write MCP POT
    const int analogOutPin_y = wiper1writeAddr; // write MCP POT

    int sensorValue_c = 0;        // value read from the PAD, Vc=Vss/2
    int sensorValue_x = 0;        // value read from the PAD, Vc=Vss/2
    int sensorValue_y = 0;        // value read from the PAD, Vc=Vss/2

    //?int outputValue_c = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
    int outputValue_x = 0;        // mid variable stored the value from 'sensorValue_c' and MAP that for use
    int outputValue_y = 0;        // mid variable stored the value from 'sensorValue_c' and MAP that for use

    int Vcr = 0;        // value read from the PAD, Vc=Vss/2
    int Vc = 0;        // value read from the PAD, Vc=Vss/2
    const int LEDpin1 = 47;
    const int LEDpin2 = 46;
    int count = 0;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      // set the slaveSelectPin as an output:
      pinMode (slaveSelectPin, OUTPUT);
      // set the shutdownPin as an output:
      pinMode (shutdownPin, OUTPUT);
      // start with all the pots shutdown
      digitalWrite(shutdownPin, LOW);
      // initialize SPI:
      SPI.begin();
      Serial.println("Setup complete");
      //??
      Serial.println("Starting loop");
      digitalWrite(shutdownPin, HIGH); //Turn off shutdown
    }

    void loop() {
      AnalogInOut(); //
      ArduinoDAC(); //
    }
    void AnalogInOut() {
      // take from some where used for testing joystick control LED,
      //need change to get date fron RC and write to MCP pots
      // read the analog in value:

      Vcr = analogRead(analogInPin_c);
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Vcr= ");
      Serial.println(Vcr);
      Vc = map(Vcr, 0, 1023, 165, 225);
      Serial.print("Vc = ");
      Serial.println(Vc);
      delay(10);
      Serial.print("count_ini= ");
      Serial.println(count);

      if (count = 0)  {

        if (Vc > 188)   {

          digitalWrite(LEDpin1, HIGH);
          Serial.print("Vc TOO HIGH: ");
          Serial.println(Vc);
          exit(0);
          delay(100);
        }

       if (Vc < 165) {

          digitalWrite(LEDpin2, HIGH);
          Serial.print("Vc TOO LOW = : ");
          Serial.println(Vc);
          exit(0);
          delay(10);
        }
        else {

          Serial.print("analogInPin_c_T00: ");
          Serial.println(analogInPin_c);

          /// digitalPotWrite(wiper0writeAddr, Vc);
          ///digitalPotWrite(wiper1writeAddr, Vc);

          digitalPotWrite(wiper0writeAddr, 100);
          digitalPotWrite(wiper1writeAddr, 220);

          count = 1;
          Serial.print("count_new= ");
          Serial.println(count);
        }
        delay(15000);
      }

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      sensorValue_x = analogRead(analogInPin_x);
      sensorValue_y = analogRead(analogInPin_y);
      // map it to the range of the analog out:
      outputValue_x = map(sensorValue_x, 0, 1023, 70, 248);
      outputValue_y = map(sensorValue_y, 0, 1023, 70, 248);  // change the analog received to the value suite for PAD joystick


      //   print the results to the Serial Monitor:
      Serial.println("sensor_x =_T10 ");
      Serial.println(sensorValue_x);
      Serial.println("sensor_y = ");
      Serial.println(sensorValue_y);
      Serial.println("\t output = ");
      Serial.println(outputValue_x);
      Serial.println(outputValue_y);

      // wait 2 milliseconds before the next loop for the analog-to-digital
      // converter to settle after the last reading:
      delay(2);
    }


    void ArduinoDAC() {
      Serial.println("Starting loop");
      digitalWrite(shutdownPin, HIGH); //Turn off shutdown

      digitalPotWrite(wiper0writeAddr, outputValue_x); // Set wiper 0 to 200

      delay(5);

      digitalPotWrite(wiper1writeAddr, outputValue_y); // Set wiper 1 to 200

      delay(5);
    }

    // This function takes care of sending SPI data to the pot.
    void digitalPotWrite(int address, int value) {
      /// Serial.print("wiper0 position_t30: ");////
      /// Serial.println();////
      // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
      digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, LOW);
      //  send in the address and value via SPI:
      SPI.transfer(address);
      SPI.transfer(value);
      delay(30);
      // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
    }

    int digitalPotRead(int address) {
      // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
      digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, LOW);
      //  send in the address via SPI:
      SPI.transfer(address);
      // send zero to read data from the address
      delay(30);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us a small and working sketch. When I see those lines, then I think: "while what?". What is the condition? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/while/

Comment: yes, it can work, because you are allowed `if` in `while`

Comment: which `delay(5000);`? ... there are two .... also, how do you know that the command does not execute?

Comment: take a coding course

Comment: Thank you for reply, I attached the code.

Comment: Now I see no delay(5000) on attached code.

Comment: @jsotola and mico , Sorry, it was delay (15000) in the original code.

Comment: Did you notice this error in your code?  if (count = 0).

Comment: `if (count = 0)` is never true. `=` is assignment to `count` and the result of assignment is the assigned value. the value is `0`

Comment: The code should read `if (count == 0)`. With a single equals it is an assignment, and the if statement evaluates the value of the right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it works.

Here you find a little sketch to see how it works. Try to transfere it to your solution.

```cpp
#include <M5Stack.h>  // only necessary for my board (M5Stack)

bool condition_while = true;
bool condition_loop = true;
int condition_if = 0;

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   while (condition_while) {
       if (condition_if == 0) {
           Serial.println("testcase #1: if path reached");
           condition_if = 1;
       }
       else if (condition_if == 1 ) {
           Serial.println("testcase #2: if else path reached");
           condition_if = 2;
       }
       else {
           Serial.println("testcase #3: else path reached");
           condition_while = false;
       }
       Serial.println("testcase #4: path reached inside while");
   }
   if (condition_loop) {
       Serial.println("testcase #5: path reached outside while");
       condition_loop = false;
   }
}
```

This is the output on COM3

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll ref. this to my code.

Comment: I can't find the line with delay(5000), can you add the line number, I also don't find a while?

Comment: @laoadam and have a look at line 77:  'if (count = 0)  {', if you want to check if count is equal to Zero you have to write  'if (count == 0)  {'

Comment: Thank you RJPlog, I did it.

Comment: @laoadam Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go through the coding tutorials on arduino website. It would be absolutely possible to have the above `structure` in an arduino code.

This link has a working and validated example showing `while` loop calling other function using `if-else-if` structure.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WhileStatementConditional?from=Tutorial.WhileLoop

Please go through the tutorials and post specific problem if and when you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

If the code (not shown) within the if/else if/else structure doesn't affect the flow of control, then either delay() placement will work.  But the placement within the loop will delay at every cycle of the loop. The placement below the loop will only delay after the loop finishes executing.

Comment: I monitor the sketch execute，even that run through but delay() in this section didn't.